# Need help inputting \multiple commands into the console in my RPG

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make an RPG in python and every time after you put in a command nothing else works and I want it to go back to the top so you can put more commands in

Comment: You need to specify your question better for us to be able to answer - e.g. posting a code example for what you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to clarify or post a little code.
Maybe try something along these lines? I'm not sure

```
def top():
  command = input("command")
  othercommand = input("command")
  if command == whatever:
    top()
top()
```